# Count and Group data based on consecutive occurrence

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

***Tricky for me to define the problem, maybe you understand it through my dummy data***.

I have this data:

```
PK, TaskPK
1, 1    
2, 1     
3, 2    
4, 2    
5, 5    
6, 1 
7, 1     
8, 2 
9, 2   
10, 5    
11, 5
```

Now I have to count `TaskPK` so, I make this query

```
Select PK, TaskPK, Count(*)
From tbl
Group by TaskPK
```

It brought this result

```
TaskPK, Count(*)
1, 4
2, 4
5, 3
```

**But I want slight different result**

Like this

```
TaskPK, Count(*)
1, 2
2, 2
5, 1
1, 2
2, 2
5, 2
```

The above result based on **consecutive data occurrence**, as TaskPK start with 1 (it group together), then it change it 2 (it group together), then 5 (it group together) taskPK. ***But as TaskPK again shifts to  1, then it should group seperatly not link with previous occurrence of 1, this task seperately count***.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you working with MySQL or you can use MariaDB that has *window functions* ?

Answer (score 5):

Problems of this kind are a *variation* of what is normally referred to as *Gaps and Islands*. You can see a good overview at [The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

### Step by step approach

This can be done with several intermediate steps. First, let's make a (derived) table, that we will store as `t1`, finding out at which points you *start a new series* of `TaskPK` values.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS
SELECT
    PK, TaskPK, 
    case when 
        (SELECT TaskPK 
         FROM tbl t_prv 
         WHERE t_prv.PK < tbl.PK 
         ORDER BY PK DESC 
         LIMIT 1
        ) <=> TaskPK 
    then 0
    else 1 
    end AS start_of_series
FROM
    tbl ;
```

`t1` contains:

```
PK | TaskPK | start_of_series
-: | -----: | --------------:
 1 |      1 |               1
 2 |      1 |               0
 3 |      2 |               1
 4 |      2 |               0
 5 |      5 |               1
 6 |      1 |               1
 7 |      1 |               0
 8 |      2 |               1
 9 |      2 |               0
10 |      5 |               1
11 |      5 |               0
```

**NOTE**: the [<=> operator in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) is equivalent to `NOT DISTINCT FROM` in standard SQL. It allows for equality comparison with NULL values as well as NON-NULL ones.

Now that we know where every series starts, we can give each `PK` a `series_number` by adding together all the *current and previous* values of the column `start_of_series` (that's a cumulative sum). Without window functions, this must be done with an (awful, inefficient) subquery.

We store the result in a table `t2`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS
SELECT
    PK, TaskPK, 
    (SELECT 
        sum(start_of_series) 
    FROM 
        t1 
    WHERE 
        t1.PK <= tbl.PK
    ) AS series_number
FROM
    tbl 
;
```

The content of `t2` is:

```
PK | TaskPK | series_number
-: | -----: | ------------:
 1 |      1 |             1
 2 |      1 |             1
 3 |      2 |             2
 4 |      2 |             2
 5 |      5 |             3
 6 |      1 |             4
 7 |      1 |             4
 8 |      2 |             5
 9 |      2 |             5
10 |      5 |             6
11 |      5 |             6
```

At this point, what you want to do is just `GROUP BY` series_number, and take the value of `TaskPK` (just `min(TaskPK)` will do this job), together with a `count(*)`:

```
SELECT
    min(TaskPK) AS TaskPK, count(*) AS count
FROM
    t2
GROUP BY
    series_number
ORDER BY
    series_number
```

This is the result you actually wanted:

```
TaskPK | count
-----: | ----:
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     5 |     1
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     5 |     2
```

### Putting everything together

By substituting `t2` and `t1` by their definitions, you can put everything together in a single query:

```
SELECT
    min(TaskPK) AS TaskPK, count(*) AS count
FROM
    (SELECT
        PK, TaskPK, 
        (SELECT 
            sum(start_of_series) 
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                PK, TaskPK, 
                case when 
                    (SELECT TaskPK FROM tbl t_prv WHERE t_prv.PK < tbl.PK ORDER BY PK DESC LIMIT 1) <=> TaskPK 
                then 0
                else 1 
                end AS start_of_series 
            FROM
                tbl
            ) AS t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.PK <= tbl.PK
        ) AS series_number
    FROM
        tbl
    ) AS t2
GROUP BY
    series_number
ORDER BY
    series_number
;
```

```
TaskPK | count
-----: | ----:
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     5 |     1
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     5 |     2
```

This query is quite complicated (there are *five* `SELECT` within it), and can probably be still simplified some.

You can find the whole code and data at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c6d66f9a434daa0fd617c73c542b080d)*

This can be very hihgly simplified if you can use [MariaDB's WINDOW functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions-overview/), or [MySQL 8.0 Window functions](https://www.slideshare.net/DagHWanvik/sql-window-functions-for-mysql) (not yet released for production as of now).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you just opened up a whole new world for me!